# Why does not display controller in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have updated Codeigniter from GitHub:
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/tree/feature/session

In `config.php` file there is rows:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

File `.htaccess:`

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

When I open URL www.site.com I get message:

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

Also I tried get controller as like:

```
index.php/articles/test
```

Comment: When using `REQUEST_URI` as `uri_protocol` try to remove `?` in your rule (otherwise i think you'll have to use `QUERY_STRING` instead). So your rule should look like this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`. If it still does not work, try also to replace `REQUEST_URI` by `PATH_INFO` in your config file

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this version on your localhost using xampp?
I got mine working the following way:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site.com/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I deleted all file and load again. When I try open controller `/home` I get message: `Internal Server Error Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server`. At localhost works.

Comment: Make sure you did change "site.com" to your actual domain.

Comment: Yes, base_url is right and works at localhost, but not at server

Comment: So you did upload it already? Make sure your $config['base_url'] value is set properly. offline example: 'http: // localhost/example.com', online example: 'http: // www.example.com' (without spaces)